# How to check for rounding off errors?

Tags: java, c, floating-point

This may be a dumb question to ask: While using float there is some rounding off done for decimal places, how to check for rounding off errors preferably in java or C? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a trick where you change the rounding mode, repeat the calculation, and see if the result is the same (if it's not the same, the difference gives you some idea how numerically stable your algorithm is). If supported, you do that in C with `fesetround` from `<fenv.h>`. But the answer to "has rounding occurred?" is almost always "yes", so you don't lose much generality if you just assume it has, and move on to wondering how much it affected the result ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do the operation in something with NO rounding, and compare the results. For example, in java you could use [Big Decimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to do an operation after you did it with float... and see if you end up with the same number.

A better question, is why do you want to do this? Float will often do weird rounds, you don't want to use it anywhere you need precision (i.e. with a banking transaction). In that case, use Big Decimal. But if you just want to represent a 3D point on the screen, 1.5 rounding to 1.499997 won't change anything...